# Не получается использовать фронтальную камеру

Tags: java, android, камера, android-camera

- Задняя камера работает прекрасно как с фото, так и с видео, но вот на фронтальную (переднюю) никак не получается перейти.
- С помощью:
  Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT; (как и другими способами)
  я определил, что фронтальной камере принадлежит индексация 1, а задней 0.
- Манифест:

  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"

  uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"

  Может существует какое-то специальное разрешение именно для фронтальной камеры? Хотя я пробовал и:

  uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"

  Причём и с false и с true на всякий случай.
- Импорт:
  import android.hardware.Camera;
  import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
- Что я пробовал:

  1. camera = Camera.open(1);
  2. params.set("camera-id",1); где, естественно, пробовал различные варианты в кавычках, которые удалось найти в интернете. Другие способы мне тоже не помогли.
- Ориентация изображения (что часто описывается при упоминании о фронтальной камере) меня сейчас волнует меньше всего. Камеры телефонов рабочие, тем более я пробовал на разных моделях. Если это имеет значение, то меня интересует только видеосъёмка на фронтальную камеру.
- Ниже очень упрощённая часть моего рабочего(!) кода (без указания файлов, настроек и др.)

  ```
    public void VideoOn(){
    params = camera.getParameters();
    //Здесь идут настройки
    camera.setParameters(params);
    if (prepareVideoRecorder()) 
    {
    mediaRecorder.start();
    } 
    else {releaseMediaRecorder();
    }
    }

    public static boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    //Здесь идут настройки
    try {mediaRecorder.prepare();}
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;}
    return true;
    }
  ```

Спасибо.

Comment: вы уже получили камеру и менять на фронтальную тут уже поздно и setCamera - deprecated. 
1. Использовать cameraX. Это упрощенный сдк для использования камеры, где суперсложных манипуляций не требуется (по описанию как раз ваш вариант). 
2. Использоваться camera2 - сложнее и многословнее. Вкратце, связываем камеру (любая, которая нужна, в CameraManager'е) и mediaRecorder через Surface. 
https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java
ну и в сэмплах https://github.com/android/camera-samples

Comment: Большое спасибо, Юрий, попробую первый вариант, его не делал. Не подскажите ещё один вопрос. Вы говорите, что "вы уже получили камеру и менять на фронтальную тут уже поздно и setCamera - deprecated" А можно ли сделать так, что бы при запуске моей программы камеры "поменялись местами" и у меня, по умолчанию, запускалась бы фронтальная камера (как сейчас задняя)?  Что в этом случаи будет с задней - мне всё равно.

Comment: Да, можно к любой камере подключаться, без переключения. просите сразу CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT. см https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/CameraXVideo/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camerax/video/fragments/CaptureFragment.kt

Answer (score 0):

С таким кодом у меня фронтальная камера заработала как часики. Код увидел у кого то на stackoverflow.

```
    public void openFrontFacingCamera() {

    int camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
    int numberOfCamera;

    numberOfCamera = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    if(camId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
        camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;

        try {
            camera.release();
            camera = Camera.open(camId);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
           //previewing = true;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }else if(camId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
        camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;

        try {
            camera.release();
            camera = Camera.open(camId);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
```